# using Oauth to access app engine pull queue from non app engine server

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth, oauth-2.0

I am trying to access my app engine applications pull queue from a separate python application. Here's what I know:

- I need to use oauth to authenticate
- I need to use Google's rest api
- I need to define a pull queue in my app engine project that has an acl list which specifies which account is granted access to the queue

I'm able to make a request to get a task from the pull queue, but it gives me an error saying `Login Required` because I haven't authenticated. I have looked through the documentation ([rest api doc](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/rest.html), [pull queue doc](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview-pull.html)), but i can't figure out how to pass in my username and password to authenticate with oauth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [google-api-python-client](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client) library.
It has a [sample](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/source/browse/#hg/samples/gtaskqueue_sample/gtaskqueue) to access the TaskQueue APIs through Oauth2 authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the [OAuth for Python overview](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/oauth/overview.html) for AppEngine? It goes over how to do the OAuth login for App Engine.

Comment: This doc is for using oauth in an app engine project. I need to use oauth in a non app engine project.